# A subspace of the $H_{0}^1(\Omega) \cap H^2(\Omega)$ is dense in a subspace of $L^2(\Omega)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, lebesgue-integral, sobolev-spaces

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ bounded open and of class $C^1$. Consider the spaces $L^2(\Omega)$, $H_0^1(\Omega)$ and $H^2(\Omega)$.

I know that $H_0^1(\Omega) \cap H^2(\Omega)$ is densely embedded in $L^2(\Omega)$ and $H_0^1(\Omega)$ is also densely embedded in $L^2(\Omega)$. Now, define
$$H_{0,m}^1(\Omega):=\left\{ f \in H_0^1(\Omega) \; ; \; \int_{\Omega} f(x) \;dx=0\right\} \quad \text{and} \quad L_{m}^2(\Omega):=\left\{ f \in L^2(\Omega) \; ; \; \int_{\Omega} f(x) \;dx=0\right\} .$$

I know that $H_{0,m}^1(\Omega)$ is closed subspace of the $H_0^1(\Omega)$, $L_{m}^2(\Omega)$ is a closed subspace of the $L^2(\Omega)$ and $H_{0,m}^1(\Omega) \cap H^2(\Omega)$ is a subspace of $L_{m}^2(\Omega)$ . Moreover $H_{0,m}^1(\Omega)$  continuously embedded in $L_{m}^2(\Omega)$ (right?).

**Question.** We have that $H_{0,m}^1(\Omega) \cap H^2(\Omega)$ is densely embedded in $L_{m}^2(\Omega)$? And $H_{0,m}^1(\Omega)$ is also densely embedded in $L^2_m(\Omega)$?

Comment: What are the $H(\Omega)$s ?

Comment: @Physor are the space defined in page $5$ [here](https://sites.icmc.usp.br/andcarva/sobolew.pdf) for $p=2$. See also equation $(34)$ in the same material.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Let $\psi \in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ with $\int_\Omega \psi \, \mathrm{d}x = 1$ be given.

For any $f \in L^2_m(\Omega)$ take a sequence $(f_n) \subset C_c^\infty(\Omega)$
with $f_n \to f$ in $L^2(\Omega)$.
Then, $\int f_n \, \mathrm dx \to \int f \, \mathrm dx$. Thus, we can define
$$
g_n := f_n - \psi \, \int_\Omega f_n \, \mathrm dx$$
and obtain
$g_n \to f$ in $L^2(\Omega)$.

Comment: But we have that $ C_c^\infty(\Omega) \subset H_{0,m}^1(\Omega) \cap H^2(\Omega), H_{0,m}^1(\Omega) $?

Comment: No, but $g_n$ has additionally mean value zero.

Comment: $(g_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset C_c^\infty(\Omega) \subset H_{0}^1(\Omega) \cap H^2(\Omega), H_{0}^1(\Omega)$ and has mean zero. That is, $$(g_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset H_{0,m}^1(\Omega) \cap H^2(\Omega), H_{0,m}^1(\Omega).$$ Right?

Comment: Yes. And I need some more characters for this comment.

Comment: What mean "And I need some more characters for this comment."?

Comment: You need 15 characters to post a comment - and "Yes." contains only 4 characters :)